# java: ClassCastException - [Ljava.lang.Long; cannot be cast to java.lang.Long

Tags: java, casting

*I use red5 and setting/getting attributes using the IConnection class, but that's really not relevant.*

'L' means long in java. so 0L is 0 type Long instead of just '0' which is 0 type Integer.

What is the difference between `[Ljava.lang.Long` and `java.lang.Long` in the following error message:

```
stack trace: java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Long; cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
```

---

**update**

code sample:

```
 static Long getLongAttribute(IConnection conn, String attribute) {
    Long result=null;
    try {
        if (!conn.hasAttribute(attribute))
            throw new Exception(attribute +  " - Long attribute not found!");
      result = conn.getLongAttribute(attribute); // <--- ERRROR ON THIS LINE
    } catch (Exception e) {
        _handleException(e);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code that causes the exception?

Comment: Know all the point of Long and array of Long, but I wonder why that line caused an exception. Here what I have from doc of red 5 http://dl.fancycode.com/red5/api/org/red5/server/api/ICastingAttributeStore.html#getLongAttribute%28java.lang.String%29 which says that method returns Long, not array of long, then why exception......

Comment: @Vishwanath: It looks like the actual problem is somewhere inside the `conn.getLongAttribute` call. There is no casting in the code presented in the question, but without a full stack trace it's hard to say exactly where the problem is. If there was a type mismatch with `result = conn.getLongAttribute` then the compiler would catch it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The first object is array of `Long`, the second is just `Long`. Try this

```
    Long l = 1l;
    Long[] l2 = {};
    System.out.println(l.getClass());
    System.out.println(l2.getClass());
```

Output

```
class java.lang.Long
class [Ljava.lang.Long;
```

But I do agree that `[L_class_;` presentation for array types is highly confusing. I wonder how it came to be that way.

Comment: The presentation is the binary class name for an array class.  It is specified in the JVM spec, and also in http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName()

Comment: The designers attempted to have internal type names that were syntactically illegal, to prevent anyone from deliberately declaring variables using those internal type names.  So you're forced to declare something as `Long[]` instead of `[Ljava.lang.long`.

Comment: @Stephen This is exactly the question, why not use a bit friendlier notation (e.g., `java.lang.Long[]`). It's not like there's any technical difficulty associated.

Comment: @TMN Could you clarify, please? What would be a problem with 'declaring variables using those internal type names'?

Comment: @TMN - not convinced that they *needed* to do that ... in the context of Java 1.1 and later.  @Nikita - the design decision was probably made *before* Java 1.0.  Mistakes were made and could not be corrected.  This is probably one of them.

Comment: OK, I can't find a reference that discusses the illegal-syntax claim, so I'll withdraw that.  What I *did* find was that the odd name isn't the type, it's actually the _field descriptor_.  It's the internal representation of the object's type.  Check out section 4.3.2 of the JVM spec.

Answer (score 2):

Your code try to cast `Long[] to Long` which causes `ClassCastException`

Answer (score 1):

`[Ljava.lang.Long` is a list of `java.lang.Long`s

EDIT: as noted below it's an array. Sorry, I typed too fast...

Comment: Technically, an *array* of longs: i.e. `Long[]`.

Comment: @Cameron Skinner: meh, I turned around to do something else and noticed my mistake and now I'm too late... ;) But yes, you are right.

Comment: @Cameron Skinner: no bad feelings ;)

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem where my code was

`List<Object[]> rows = criteria.list();`

But my criteria has just count(*) projection and hence `criteria.list()` returns just `List<Long>` instead of `List<Long[]>`

I resolved it by changing it to

`List<Object> rows = criteria.list();`