# Casting ArrayList<Long> to a Long[] Array fails with method toArray()

Tags: java, generics

The following code unexpectatly throws the error shown below.

```
public static Long[] factorize() {
        final ArrayList<Long> returnValue = new ArrayList<>();
        return (Long[]) returnValue.toArray();
}

java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Long;
    at primes2019.Factorization.factorize(Factorization.java:69)
    at primes2019.Factorization.main(Factorization.java:13)
```

Comment: There is another `.toArray(...)` method overload that you should be using. One that includes a `Long[]` parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the lightning fast help.

Comment: You're welcome -- has your problem been solved?

Comment: Yeah, just needed to add 'returnValue.toArray(new Long[0])' and now it's a 'Long[]' instead of 'Object[]'

Comment: Good deal. Note for future reference -- searching on the error message: [java arraylist toarray classcastexception site:stackoverflow.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+arraylist+toarray+classcastexception+site:stackoverflow.com) brought me the duplicate quickly. A search like this is a good tool to have in your arsenal.

Comment: Yeah, when my first search didn't turn up something useful I concluded the error wasn't existing in this form on the site. Everyone searches differently^^. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510354/java-classcastexception-ljava-lang-long-cannot-be-cast-to-java-lang-long here is the thread I found first

Comment: Indeed, thanks for sharing that. Your search was a bit too specific it looks like